# Query for group summary like report

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2000

I have a table as given below

```
ID     value       
----   ------  
1      A1           
1      A2        
1      A3           
2      B1        
2      B2        
2      B3
```

I need to write a query using SQL Server 2000 that shows output as given below

```
ID       value       
----     ------  
1         A1           
Null      A2        
Null      A3           
2         B1        
Null      B2        
Null      B3
```

Comment: sorry for formatting issues , ID column have values 1 , 2 and  Value column have values A1..A3 , B1...B3

Comment: Ouch...you still have to use sql 2000? This formatting really should be left to the front end. It is ugly enough with the "newer" window functions but in sql 2000 this type of thing is just ugly.

Comment: Upgrade already :) Mainstream support for SQL Server 2000 ended almost seven years ago (and extended support almost two years ago).

Comment: In my company we were using SQL Server 2000 together with .Net 1.1 (!!!) until recently. This really hurts!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This kind of report style formatting is better to do in a proper reporting application, but it can be done on the server too.

If you had used a SQL Server version >= 2005 (which you really should by now) you could have used window functions to accomplish this quite easily like this:

```
select case when rn = 1 then id else null end as id, value 
from (
    select *, rn = row_number() over (partition by id order by id, value) 
    from your_table
    ) a
```

but since you're using an ancient version without the `row_number` function we have to emulate that somehow. One way is to use a running count of rows in a correlated subquery - this should work although it won't be particularly efficient.

```
select 
    case when (
       select count(*) 
       from your_table 
       where value <= t1.value 
       and ID = t1.ID
    ) = 1 then ID 
       else null end as id
       , value
from your_table as t1
```

Since I don't have access to any server with the old version I couldn't test it, but I can't see any obvious reason that it shouldn't work.

Comment: this approach works but then in my actual table [value] field contains string with multiple characters including special characters and because of this order of ID column messed up. Got to use another field equivalent to ID to set the order as expected.

Answer (score 1):

Concurring with the consensus that this is best done in the presentation layer but one way of doing this in SQL would be

```
SELECT fv.ID,
       T1.value
FROM   Table1 T1
       LEFT JOIN (SELECT ID,
                         MIN([value]) AS FirstVal
                  FROM   Table1
                  GROUP  BY ID) AS fv
         ON T1.ID = fv.ID
            AND T1.value = fv.FirstVal
ORDER  BY T1.ID,
          T1.value
```

Comment: That's way smarter than my contrived numbering scheme, guess I was to locked into to the numbering approach to consider anything else :)